# Включение Bluetooth программно

Tags: android, сокет, bluetooth

Необходимо включить Bluetooth и сделать его видимым(на бесконечное кол-во времени или хотябы на 3-4 часа) для всех устройств.

Сейчас делаю так:

```
public void EnabledBluetooth(Activity activity){/* включаем блютуз и делаем его видимым*/
        Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
        int dur = 0; // или // 300;
        discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, dur);
        activity.startActivityForResult(discoverableIntent, Constants.REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
    }
```

Этот код работает, но не на всех устройствах.

Работает на DNS 4003, HTC one, xiaomi redmi node 3, а на Fly IQ4412 Quad не работает (блютуз включается но его видимость устанавливается в 1,59 минуты)

Что можете подсказать? Реально сделать так чтобы на всех устройствах работало? Куда копать? Может еще какие то параметры нужно передавать в Intent`е?

Comment: а нельзя просто таймер на эти 2 минуты поставить и постоянно включать?

Comment: В таком случае пользователь должен нажимать кнопку подтверждения - это мне не подходит